# Selection rules in atomic physics . Why is $j' = 0$ to $j=0$ transition not allowed?

Tags: photons, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, atomic-physics

Consider the quantum numbers  j (total angular momentum) and l (angular momentum) where j = l + s.
My notes state that:

Delta l can only be 1 or -1. 
Delta j can only equal 1 or zero, because the photon carries away one
unit of angular momentum.

My question: 
A transition from j' = 0 to j = 0 is forbidden. Why is it this the case?

Comment: What is j' in your notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By angular momentum coupling, the possible $j_f$ values for the final states must be contained in the decomposition of 
$$
j_i\otimes (L=1)= \vert j_i-1\vert\oplus \ldots \oplus j_i+1\, .
$$ 
In your case, the initial angular momentum $j_i=0$ so that 
$$
0 \otimes 1 =1
$$
and no other value of $j_f$ except $j_f=1$ can occur.  Thus $j_f=0$ Is excluded by triangularity of the angular momentum coupling.