# How is total angular momentum conserved in electric dipole transitions for $ΔJ = 0$ in a multi-electron atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, dipole

One of the selections rules is that

`ΔJ=0,±1`

for an electric dipole transition in a multi-electron atom, where J is the total angular momentum. Since

`ΔS=0`

(as spin is not affected), the change in total orbital angular momentum is also 0 or ±1. Could someone give me a *physical* example how a zero change is possible? As far as I can understand, the change is ±1 for a *single*-electron atom and cannot be 0. The photon emitted carries the ±1 angular momentum away and hence angular momentum is conserved. We only consider 1 electron transitioning at a time, so I don't understand how the overall angular momentum change can be 0 then, if it can't be 0 for a single electron atom. I've been trying to look this up but the furthest I got was "this is just possible because of how angular momentum combines".

Could someone describe a real example to me how this works in practice?

Comment: related to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445901

Comment: @zerothehero thanks, but the sources mentioned there still only talk about rules and how it's possible, there is no mention of a real example unfortunately.

Comment: what do you mean by “real example”?  The identification of an atom and an energy level?  why won’t $\vert \ell=1,m=1\rangle \to \vert \ell=1,m=0\rangle$ do?  Remember that angular momentum is a vector so it’s perfectly possible to vectorially add the angular momentum of the photon to that of the state to get a state with final value of angular moment: add to vectors with relative angle $60^o$ to form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Is your lowercase L the total orbital angular momentum? By real example, I mean that how do the electrons rearrange themselves in a multi-electron atom so that ΔL=0? The vector model is about arrows only, I wanted something like an electron dropping from 3s->2p level and in that case how does ΔL end up being zero. (e.g. what rearrangements happen with other electrons?)

Comment: Well of course for $3s\to 2p$ $\Delta L$ is NOT zero since $p$ states have $L=1$ and while $s$ states have $L=0$.  You need to look at some transitions of the $3p\to 2p$ type or something like this.  See https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7abe/c81f5b1f78e082aba06939fd7af6b9f3777b.pdf for a nice discussion of applicability of vector model.

Comment: But 3p->2p is forbidden for electric dipole transitions,  Δ_lowercase_L= 0 is not allowed (change in angular momentum of a single electron), yet ΔL=0 (total orbital angular momentum of a multielectron system) is still somehow possible for an electric dipole transition. It puzzles me because we only consider one electron jump at a time for such transitions. I think you're misunderstanding what I'm asking. (and change in spin is also 0, adding to its weirdness)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero So, using your example, the electron transition from state l=1 ml=1 to state l=1 ml=0 would mean that a photon with an angular momentum -1 (spin down) was absorbed. In this case we make a vector sum of the electron orbital angular momentum +1 (ml =1) with the photon angular momentum -1 (spin down) and both vectors cancel each other on the z direction, and in the end of the day we have a l=1 ml=0 electron, with no angular momentum on the z direction, but still with the same magnitude of angular momentum (because the transition didn't change the quantum number l). Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

A good example when $\Delta J = 0$ is a Rubidium D1 line transition:

$$ 5 ^2 \text{S}_{1/2} \rightarrow 5 ^2 \text{P}_{1/2} $$

at 795 nm. In that case: $\Delta S = 0$ and the only available electron changes its angular momentum $l$ by 1 (from 0). In that case, you have two available resultant $J=\{1/2, 3/2\}$. Both of them relate to different "orientations" of $l$ with respect to electron spin $s$. By the way, the transition to state $J=3/2$ is a well-known D2 transition at 780 nm.

Regarding $\Delta L = 0$, I provided an example with an explanation in that post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/750497/358408 .